# Concept of tangent and residual in AceFem and automation

Tags: equation-solving, finite-element-method, automation, calculus-and-analysis

here trying to solve the pde: ut + ux = 0 in acefem. I have two questions regarding tangent and residual.

1. Tangent shows the `s$$` and residual shows `p$$` in the acefem code.
   There are two parts comes under `p$$` and `s$$` which are connected through `p$$`, "AddIn" -> True `and s$$, "AddIn" -> True` respectively.
   Here I could not able to understand that what does this " `"AddIn" -> True` " does to the `p$$` and `s$$`? Does it shows the direct addition of first part and second part of `p$$`?

   2. How exactly SMSStandardModule["Tangent and residual"] works in acefem. I have already checked with acefem help in mathematica. It seems to me that it operates upon default standard user subroutine for tangent and residual. If yes then I would like to see that how does the subroutine looks and works.
      I also checked the default acefem codes for solving the pde with finite element method.
      There, by directly using  SMSStandardModule["Tangent and residual"] will gives the solution. But in the case of above mentioned pde, I need to provide each entry of `p$$` and `s$$` manually. So is there any way to create `p$$` and `s$$` automatically?

   Your suggestion's to make it automaticlly would be helpful to understand the concept.
   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Examples in the manual are a good start for all questions.

1. AddIn: SMSExport[a,b] traslates to a=b
   SMSExport[a,b,"AddIn"->True] traslates to a=a+b
2. AceGen generates C, Fortran, ... codes. Please run one of the examples in the manual and look at the generated source codes files.
3. The input for AceGen can not be a PDE as such. You have to transform PDE into a set of algebraic equations first using FEM, BEM, finite difference, finite volume, or any other of many discretization methods.